# Javascript and JQuery - Inserting DOM into JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, variables, fancybox

Ok here is my issue I have a box that shows a user's FB Pic to confirm their input, but im having an issue figuring out how to get what the user types in the input box to apear in the link that's inside of the JQuery function.

**Here is the script**

```
  $("#fb").blur(function(){
   $.fancybox(
   '<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/ *user's input here* /picture?type=large"/> <br> is that you? ',
      {
       'autoDimensions' :  true,
       'transitionIn'   : 'none',
       'transitionOut'  : 'true'
      }
    );
   });
```

**Here is the HTML Form**

```
<input type="text" id="fb" size="10" name="fb" value="" />
```

How can I get whatever is typed in that input box to apear in that link in the script when the function is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you would fetch the value from the input field and then just use string addition to build the string you want like this:

```
 $("#fb").blur(function(){
   var text = this.value;
   $.fancybox(
   '<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/' + text + '/picture?type=large"/> <br> is that you? ',
      {
       'autoDimensions' :  true,
       'transitionIn'   : 'none',
       'transitionOut'  : 'true'
      }
    );
   });
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. I have been doing a lot of programing with PHP but was having a little difficulty with javascript variables. If you are curious its for a registration form when a user puts a Facebook Unique ID in the form field and a little pop box comes up with their profile picture to confirm their ID. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use [`$(this).val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val):

```
$("#fb").blur(function() {
    var t   = $(this).val();
    var img = '<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'
            + encodeURIComponent(t)
            + '/picture?type=large"/>';
    $.fancybox(img + '<br/>is that you?', {
        //...
    });
});
```

Assuming that your text input is `<input id="fb" type="text">` of course, then `this` will be that text input inside the blur handler.

Comment: $(this).val() was useful, But I had difficulty how you included that variable in the link. I see how it works, but I want to keep it simple  so that when I come back to the code later it's easier to understand. The user that I selected as the answer hit the nail on the head. Thank you!